# endless scrolling does not work

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, scroll

**Update: My Github Repository https://github.com/Marc585/smartforce2**

i just finished the onemonthrails tutorial. at the last chapter its about endless scrolling. i tripple checked my code but it just doesn't work. I don't get an error or anything. It just doesn't do anything. I'm building a pinterest clone and after i scroll to the bottom it should load the next page of pins.

This is my pins.js.coffee

```
# Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
# All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
# You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/

jQuery ->
    $('#pins').imagesLoaded ->
        $('#pins').masonry itemSelector: ".box"

    if $('.pagination').length
        $(window).scroll ->
            url = $('.pagination .next_page a').attr('href')
            if url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50
                # What to do at the bottom of the page
                $('.pagination').text("Fetching more pins...")
                $.getScript(url)
            $(window).scroll()
```

This is my index.js.erb

```
$boxes = $('<%= j render(@pins) %>')

$('#pins').append( $boxes ).imagesLoaded( function(){
    $('#pins').masonry( 'reload');
});
<% if @pins.next_page %>
    $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate(@pins) %>');
<% else %>
    $('.pagination').remove();
<% end %>
```

This is my pins controller:

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index]

  # GET /pins
  # GET /pins.json
  def index
    @pins = Pin.order("created_at desc").page(params[:page]).per_page(20)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @pins }
      format.js
    end
  end

  # GET /pins/1
  # GET /pins/1.json
  def show
    @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @pin }
    end
  end

  # GET /pins/new
  # GET /pins/new.json
  def new
    @pin = current_user.pins.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @pin }
    end
  end

  # GET /pins/1/edit
  def edit
    @pin = current_user.pins.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /pins
  # POST /pins.json
  def create
    @pin = current_user.pins.new(params[:pin])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @pin.save
        format.html { redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @pin, status: :created, location: @pin }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @pin.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /pins/1
  # PUT /pins/1.json
  def update
    @pin = current_user.pins.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @pin.update_attributes(params[:pin])
        format.html { redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @pin.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /pins/1
  # DELETE /pins/1.json
  def destroy
    @pin = current_user.pins.find(params[:id])
    @pin.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to pins_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Error Message from my developer tools
https://www.dropbox.com/s/odqknmw7np1f4cv/Bildschirmfoto%202013-08-31%20um%2014.34.40.png

Comment: Does your `scroll` callback get called? Is `url` what you expect it to be? Have you checked the other values in that `if`?

Comment: @muistooshort unfortunately i have no idea what that means that you just said. i'm a ROR beginner. i just added my github repository. if you could have a look that would be awesome. thanks

Comment: Well, time to learn a bit of debugging then. Try adding some `console.log` calls to the CoffeeScript to see if your callback gets called. And check the requests in your browser's developer tools to see what the server and browser are saying to each other.

Comment: I would love to learn how to debug. i googled a lot about it but weren't able to find a good tutorial or anything like this on where to set what in my code and where to get logfiles. i attached a screenshot in my post of the browser dev tools but i don't know what to do with the error message. other stack overflow postings to that error didn't help me yet.

Comment: Do you need to include the ImagesLoaded (http://desandro.github.io/imagesloaded/) plugin on your page? You are calling an imagesLoaded method that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing

format.js in your show action in the pins_controller.rb. This is from the onemonth rails notes

Note: You'll have to create an analogous show.js.erb and add the format.js option to your users#show action to get endless scroll to work on users' profile pages as well

```
def show
@pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @pin }
  format.js
 end
end
```

Your show.js.erb should look like this

```
boxes = $('<%= j render(@pins) %>')

$('#pins').append( $boxes ).imagesLoaded( function(){
   $('#pins').masonry( 'reload');
});
<% if @pins.next_page %>
   $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate(@pins) %>');
<% else %>
   $('.pagination').remove();
<% end %>
```